do the editor's write rewrite all the bytes on the disk or just the diff?
For example, i'm using neovim and have 200KB file size, when i hit :w to save it, do it gonna rewrite all the bytes in my nvme cells or it will compare the changes and "append" it? I think this question depends on low level things that i'm not totally aware of
Can someone try to explain this system call for writing and the relation with the hardware? I tried to search it but not find similar questions on the internet
